# How to create a new CFLAG in CMAKE and use it in the code as #ifdef

Tags: cmake

I am trying to create a new makefile variable and if I compile with that flag, kick in a certain piece of code.. For example

```
"make -p my_app"

in my_app.c
....

#ifdef R_IS_SET
   blah_blah
#else
   foo_foo
```

In the above, somehow the "-p" should translate to "R_IS_SET" as true...Now what changes do I need to make in my CMakeFile to achieve this. Please suggest

Comment: `create a new makefile variable` ` in my CMakeFile` So Makefile, CMakeFile or preprocessor? What research did you do? Surely there are many cmake and make introduction on the net - many of them will tackle how to pass definitions to C preprocessor using command line arguments when configuring the build system. `somehow the "-p"` Sorry, but `make` does not allow variables with leading `-`. It's unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I tried this adding "CFLAGS=-DTYRME" and used it in the .c file as #ifdef TRYME .... This worked, however now I am trying to find how can I map a make arguement or a make target to enabling the -DTRYME..